react-native how to login to instagram IOS?
I'm trying to make a simple program to get a number of instagram followers of a user who provide permissions to do so on my app.
For this, as I understand from Meta documentation, I need to login with Facebook and get AccessToken. To connect to Facebook I found react-native-fbsdk-next library which I managed to setup. Next I created a function for Button onPress as follow:
import { LoginButton, AccessToken, GraphRequest, GraphRequestManager, LoginManager, AuthenticationToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk-next';


const handleFacebookLogin = async () => {

  try{
      const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile','email','instagram_basic','pages_show_list']);

      if(result.isCancelled){
        console.log('Login Cancelled');
      }
      else{
        const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if(!data){
          console.log('Something went wrong obtaining access token');
        }
        else {
          console.log(data.accessToken.toString())
          console.log(data.getPermissions())
          const user_public = await axios.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/me?&access_token=${data.accessToken.toString()}`)
          console.log(user_public.data)
        }
      }
    }
    catch (error){
      console.log("Login fail with error: ", error)
    }
  }

<Button onPress={handleFacebookLogin}  title='Login with Facebook'/>

As a result I'm getting a prompt to login:


The problems are:

The permissions which I'm retrieving in console.log(data.getPermissions()) are different from requested - why instagram_basic not added even though requested

My access token not accepted to get even public information like name & id

What gives me LimitedAccess and what I should de with it

Do I really need to connect from Facebook to get access to Instagram Graph API.

The workflow of how to get the number of Instagram followers not clear.

All examples which I'm finding on stack overflow or over internet almost not working in 2024.


Here is program log output:

I cannot find any proper explanation and/or documentation.
Any thoughts would be helpful, I'm trying to do it already more then 2 month.
Also if anybody can share working example of how to connect react-native application to Instagram Graph API to retrieve user information, will help a lot.
